# Only 255 character should be entered into textarea using html and css(without javascript)

Tags: html, css, textarea

My Textarea should accept only 255 character(space included).

I tried using maxlength property in html but it was not working.

**sample code**

```
<table border="0">

                    <tr>
                        <td><form:textarea id="textarea" path="Comments"
                                maxlength="255" readonly="false" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="CANCEL" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

NOTE: 1. NOT MORE THAN 255 CHARACTER ARE ALLOWED.
      2. WITHOUT USING JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: remove the `form:` from the front of the text area tag and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in the context of a HTML5 doctype, `maxlength` should work fine. You just need to tweak the HTML a little bit:

```
<form>
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea id="textarea" name="comments" maxlength="255"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" /></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="CANCEL" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Note that I've omitted the `readonly` attribute. It's not necessary since the default value already is `false`.

**Edit**

Although this would work in some browsers, you need to be sure about which browsers your solution needs to support. To be able to support this feature in legacy browsers a JavaScript solution would be advised.

Comment: if i remove the form: my whole page got collapse.please provide another way

Comment: I've edited my answer with sample code in stead of the description I previously provided.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the `path` attribute in the `<textarea>` is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: i m doing this html with spring.so value added in textarea will directly given to the attribute in its entity class

Answer (score 4):

The `maxlength` attribute for `textarea` elements in new in HTML 5. Support for it is not universal.

If you want wide support for client-side limits on the content that can be added to a textarea then you have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This code given me answer for this question:

```
<table border="1">
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:textarea id="textarea" path="Comments" size="maxlength"
                            maxlength="255" readonly="false" /> <input type="submit"
                        name="submit" value="OK" /> <input type="submit"
                        name="submit" value="CANCEL" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Thanks for others help!